# Good (standardized) methodology to specify binary telegrams/protocols

Tags: xml, xsd, binary, specifications, requirements

I'm looking for a technical specification methodology to specify binary data.
I'm looking for something like an XML Schema Description (XSD) is for XML.

The aim is to use the format to generate programs that can interprete binary sequences correctly; i.e. a programming language binding. This would be just like there are many frameworks for XSD which can generate Classes in OO-Programming language that can represent XML-Data, parse and serialize.
Still, the methodology needs to be highly human-readable such that domain experts can specify and interprete this textual specification.

So far I only found human-readable syntaxes. In many standards ASCII-Art is used, like in [RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) or [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/resources/download) like this:

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                        Sequence Number                        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
| Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
|       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                    Options                    |    Padding    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                             data                              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                        TCP Header Format
```

However, this is hardly machine readable.

Sometimes I saw specifications in [Extended Backus Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). However, this is not really readable by technical domain-people and I am not really aware of a standard that suggests this method to specify binary data.

Can anyone suggest a suitable methodology/standard?

Cheers,
Hauke

Comment: ASN.1 is sometimes used to specify binary formats.  But if you have "technical" people who cannot read (or learn to read) EBNF, the chances that they will be happy with ASN.1 appear slender.  (How can they be technical people if they don't know how to read a context-free grammar?  You have my profound sympathy.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is wonderfully expressed but presupposes that there is a *single* format that is ideal for meeting conflicting constraints.

Instead, *separately* choose the best format for human and machine consumption, and automatically convert between them.  Depending upon your needs, this mapping can be fully bidirectional, or one format may be singularly derived from the other.

Once you adopt the automatic conversion pattern, you'll find you're no longer over-constraining the solution space, and you'll be able to optimize for what's really two separate sets of goals (the needs of the human and the needs of the machine), not one combined set.